# Having Methods Take Constant Parameters (The Java Programming Language 4th Edition Exercise 2.17 Arnold, Gosling, Holmes)

Tags: java, overloading

There is an exercise in the "The Java Programming Language 4th Edition" book:
Exercise 2.17: Add two `turn` methods to `Vehicle`: one that takes a number of degrees to turn and one
that takes either of the constants `Vehicle.TURN_LEFT` or `Vehicle.TURN_RIGHT`.

There isn't further information what data type do these constants have - the only information is that the class has attribute `direction` of type `int` representing degrees (on a plane).

The idea is to use overloading but if we have:

```
 public class Vehicle {
    public final static int TURN_LEFT = -90;
    public final static final int TURN_RIGHT = 90;

    ...

    public void turn(int degrees) {
        this.currentDirection = degrees;
    }

    public void turn (???) {
       ???
    }
}
```

What could be the definition of the overloaded `turn` method taking the 2 constants? They are also of type `int` so what other `turn` method signature would be possible (one that takes 1 of the 2 possible constants)?

Is there a way to force a method to only take particular constant parameters?

I know one can use an `enum` to define `TURN_LEFT` and `TURN_RIGHT` in a special type, which could be used as (filtered) parameter for the `turn` method, but the constants are already given as members of the Vehicle class ... so is this some bad defined exercise or is there some other trick here?

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether `enum`s were treated. In that case an enum is ideal:

```
public enum Turn {
    TURN_LEFT(-90),
    TURN_RIGHT(90);

    public final int degrees;

    Turn(int degrees) {
        this.degrees = degrees;
    }
}

public static final Turn TURN_LEFT = Turn.TURN_LEFT;
public static final Turn TURN_RIGHT = Turn.TURN_RIGHT;

public void turn(Turn direction) {
    turn(direction.degrees);
}
```

I duplicated the enum constants as final fields in order to have a Vehicle.TURN_LEFT.

---

***Without enum:***

```
public static final Object TURN_LEFT = new Object();
public static final Object TURN_RIGHT = new Object();

public void turn(Object direction) {
    turn(direction == Vehicle.TURN_LEFT ? -90 : 90);
}
```

But that is not type safe, which would need a local class/interface.

Comment: no `enum` s were not treated so far (they come later in the book) and most importantly - `TURN_LEFT` and `TURN_RIGHT` are members of the class `Vehicle` - they are given as Vehicle.TURN_LEFT and so on ... only their type is not given - but it is logical to assume  `int` I think.

Comment: OK :) I voted up because of "I duplicated the enum constants as fina ..." so all of the conditions are fulfilled. But this would mean the exercise is just not so good. (if there isn't some other trick there)

Comment: One could make two `String` or `boolean` constants, so turn might be overloaded. Or very dirty a `double`. I'll add some code.

Comment: I thought that too, but it again points to a bad exercise formulation ...

Answer (score 0):

Because the only two possibilities are LEFT or RIGHT, I would associate each one of them with a boolean, for example LEFT -> true, RIGHT -> false and I will pass the argument a boolean. Like :

```
public void turn ( boolean leftOrRight ) { // do the checking on the value passed as a boolean
 }
```

Comment: yes there are many possible ways in general. But the question is about this specific  exercise - using overloading with the constants given as parameters ... what other `turn` method signature would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to deal with such kind of constants in Java is indeed, as you mentioned, the use of enums. You then overload your method `turn()` with both an integer and your enum type parameter. The advantage is a separation of your actual class and the different (maybe upcoming) directions to steer in.